# Are contests appropriate for meta?

Tags: discussion

I have a odd question, would it be ok to run contests in meta? something like "Who can make the best looking house" I think this would be a fun thing to do and wouldn't negatively affect the site. [This](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) SE site does something similar. What do you think about this?

Comment: Well, strictly speaking, not really, that's not the purpose of meta but several SE sites hold small events like these. We were planning some community building activities for the site but real world stuff takes up quite a bit of our time so not much left for us to organize and oversee things like these. It's not as simple as just making a post asking for submissions under a theme etc. Maybe in the coming holidays we could hold a small competition of sorts. Let's see what happens.

Comment: @iKlsR I agree that meta shouldn't be used for contest stuff, after I saw your look of disapproval (http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13346875#13346875) I wonder whether you're against the chat-room, wasn't the Showroom intented for things like that? Could you please add a post on the plans? ">> We were planning some community building activities".

Comment: @stacker Heh, ignore that ;). It's perfectly fine to use chat as long as it's related to what the site is about for the most part. We once had [scheduled chats](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scheduled-chat) but not enough participants so we put that on hold. I can't say exactly what yet as this would have to be discussed some more.

Answer (score 2):

While this may be fun, its really not the purpose of stackexchange or meta, such competitions can be run on forums and other community channels.

While not especially harmful its a distraction.

Comment: Would it be ok if I made a chat room for this?

Comment: @Qwertie That should be ok.