# Add contests on blender exchange

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, site-promotion

In light of our recent event aiming to improve our answer ratio. I think it would be a good idea to consider adding contests to blender.stackexchange.com. The stackexchange site [Code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) has a [9.5](http://codemanteau.com/stacker/?siteId=88) answer ratio. That answer ratio is more attainable, we already have more daily visits then that site does.

[Contests](http://www.blendernation.com/category/blender-community/contests/) in the blender community seem to generate a lot of activity such as "[Weekend Contest: Default Cube](http://www.blendernation.com/2014/04/11/weekend-contest-default-cube/)." I feel that it would benefit this site in many ways to add a contest following something along the lines of Bart's Weekend Contests.

A new [contests](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contests) tag would be used for the contests. We could follow the same type of guidelines as code golf does for its contests. I have other ideas for the contests, and if the community thinks it a good thing to add to the site, then I shall share them.

I know that contests were talked about for the meta: "[Are contests appropriate for meta?](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331/are-contests-appropriate-for-meta)", but I think this is different enough to warnte another post.

Comment: +10! :D Would love to see what people would do if we had a [tag:default-cubism] tag.. ;)

Comment: That's an amazing idea!

Comment: I'm all for it! if we can get our mods and power users to vouch for this, then I don't think anyone will cause trouble. :)

Comment: Maybe a contest idea to start with can be something along the lines of "Who can do the best job of porting a specific 'Yo Frankie' game level to modern Blender 2.7x."  If Campbell Barton and Dalai Felinto agree to review and judge; the contest will have the benefit of also contributing directly to Blender Foundation Development.

Comment: @MarcClintDion That sounds like a very big project.. I got the sense these would be more like small "weekend contests" like you see on blendernation. Plus it would be hard for the community to vote on, as the results would visually be more or less the same.. (Not sure if having developers judge contests is a better use of their time than coding..)

Comment: It saves them from having to do it themselves and that leaves them free to code.

Comment: The Yo Frankie levels all load more or less properly.  It's the logic bricks that seem to need repairing.  That's pretty small since a person would just have to use the old version as reference and add the modern bricks that work with 2.72

Comment: Here is a mini level .blend from Yo Frankie that I drag and dropped into 2.72. So the idea would be that whoever does the best job of repairing it will be the winner. It's a given that different people will have skill in repairing different areas so many people will all end up with partial solutions to the whole problem and this leaves the core devs free to work on the big stuff without having to do several weeks of chores. The students do the rough work instead. ;) http://www.pasteall.org/pic/79628

Comment: I think this is a great idea!

Answer (score 3):

Sorry to be the grump here but this isn't going to happen. Code golf was intended to be used like that, we have a stricter scope and I don't think contests should mingle with serious questions on the main site much less introducing new tags for these, as for helping the answer ratio, these would just be superfluous and in poor taste.

On the other hand, I for one wouldn't mind overseeing this on *meta* (seeing how many people are interested) in a manner similar to what [Anime.se](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/events) had but it won't happen on the main site.

Comment: Contests like this held on Meta could possibly generate a lot of activity on the main site because we would then see many questions like the following.  http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18683/how-do-i-fix-the-texface-conversion-problem-message-when-importing-yo-frankie/18684#18684

Comment: @MarcClintDion Yes, we would most likely have an event to go along with the contest and these will show up on the bulletin board.