# New tag for fun challenges

Tags: discussion, tags, questions

This question [What's the fastest and / or craziest way to model an arrow in Blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/100203/29586) made me wonder if we need a new tag - eg, ‘Challenge’ - to flag such questions to make them easier to follow and spot for anyone interested in this kind of thing, so i wondered what everyone else thought... or is there already a preferred method of handling such things? Or are these kind of questions not appropriate for BSE and should be migrated elsewhere? Any thoughts, comments, objections, suggestions?

Comment: I just realised noClue beat me to it to ask this question https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2445/29586